# How to create a custom android menu screen layout with Eclipse?

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried to see if anyone had a similar question but had no luck. I've been trying to figure how to build a layout like this:

[image: Image with Layout I'm trying to achieve.]

I've tried a few different layouts initially I thought table might work since it's just a 2 column table with a 2 row table on the left and a 2 x 2 row/column table on the right side, however `TableLayout` doesn't work how I thought (I couldn't figure out how to add columns). Grid seems to get me close but that only seems to work if I were to do a full grid of Buttons instead of trying to break up the screen into the sections like in the image.

Does anyone have any advice or could point me in the right direction on how something like this could be best achieved?

I don't have enough rep to post the solution but here's a quick version of the code that now looks similar to this layout (only buttons aren't scaled and the title is an image):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainMenu" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageButton03"
    android:layout_marginRight="108dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ImageButton03"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageButton02"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton05"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: Apparently the issue I was having was trying to add layouts within a layout.  I tried a completely clean (deleted everything in the xml then added the layout) RelativeLayout and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how i designed before I so you figured it out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```